# Avr file hex address overlapped problem

Tags: avr, hex

I am writing one microbasic codes for atmega 32 ,the program works on Proteus simulation but when i want to program it the programmer got this error:

***file hex address overlapped problem***

So the Codes are:

```
    program MyProject
' Lcd module connections
dim LCD_RS as sbit at PORTb0_bit
dim LCD_EN as sbit at PORTb2_bit
dim LCD_D4 as sbit at PORTb4_bit
dim LCD_D5 as sbit at PORTb5_bit
dim LCD_D6 as sbit at PORTb6_bit
dim LCD_D7 as sbit at PORTb7_bit

dim LCD_RS_Direction as sbit at DDb0_bit
dim LCD_EN_Direction as sbit at DDb2_bit
dim LCD_D4_Direction as sbit at DDb4_bit
dim LCD_D5_Direction as sbit at DDb5_bit
dim LCD_D6_Direction as sbit at DDb6_bit
dim LCD_D7_Direction as sbit at DDb7_bit

dim on_a_0 as integer
 dim hours, minutes, seconds, day, week, month, year as byte
' Declarations section 

dim txt,txt_inin as string[6]
dim kp,ok,k_set,chanel,Pwm_Percent,Pwm_chanel ,on_off as  integer


sub procedure Lcd_0()
              Lcd_Init()
              Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CLEAR)               ' Clear display
              Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CURSOR_OFF)          ' Cursor off

end sub
main:
'   Main program 
for chanel =1 to 1
'     for week =1to 7
     for Pwm_chanel=1 to 1
     on_a_0  =0
     on_a_0 =0
     on_a_0  =0
     on_a_0 =0
      Delay_mS(1000)
      next pwm_chanel
'      next week
      next chanel

 while True


 for chanel =1 to 2
'     for week =1to 7
     for Pwm_chanel=1 to 2
     if  (on_a_0 >= hours ) and (on_a_0 ) then
         if    (on_a_0 >= minutes)  and (on_a_0)then
           Lcd_0()
           Lcd_Out(1,1,"on pwm mode")
           inttostr(chanel,txt)                     ' ??? ????? ???? ? ?????? ????? ? ????
           LCD_Out(1,13, txt)
           inttostr(on_off,txt)                     ' ??? ????? ???? ? ?????? ????? ? ????
           LCD_Out(2,1, txt)
           inttostr(pwm_chanel,txt)                     ' ??? ????? ???? ? ?????? ????? ? ????
           LCD_Out(2,4, txt)
         end if
      else
        Lcd_0()
        inttostr(on_a_0 ,txt)                     ' ??? ????? ???? ? ?????? ????? ? ????
           LCD_Out(1,11, txt)
            inttostr(week,txt)
            LCD_Out(2,11, txt)
           Lcd_Out(1,1,"offfff")
            Delay_mS(100)
      end if
'      Delay_mS(1000)
      next pwm_chanel
'      next week
      next chanel


 wend
end.
```

and the file files (codes and Proteus ) are accessible by this link:

http://filepi.com/i/ep8bQ7y

Thanks a lot for your attention.

Comment: the zip file is empty

Comment: empty link removed with working links, thanks jippie

Comment: You did try to open the archive yourself, right?

Comment: file error fixed !!!

Comment: Looks like there are multiple files combined in the .hex file, not just the program for the processor.